# Is it possible to declare a keyword with arguments inside the name?

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to declare a keyword in the following format:

```
Environment variable    SOME_DIR   is   C:\\Something
```

I've tried doing it via this decorator:

```
@keyword(name = "Environment variable ${name} is ${value}")
def setEnvVar(self, name, value):
    # ...
```

But it is not recognized when I try to call it:

```
No keyword with name 'Environment variable' found.
```

Is this syntax possible in Robot Framework? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're defining the keyword is correct. The way you are calling it in your test is not.

When you use two or more spaces between items in a statement, robot uses that to determine the keyword name and arguments. Thus, when you do `Environment variable    SOME_DIR   is   C:\\Something`, it see it as the keyword `Environment variable` followed by the arguments `SOME_DIR`, `is`, and `C:\\Something`.

Since you are using embedded arguments, you can't use multiple spaces. You need to call the keyword like this:

```
environment variable SOME_DIR is c:\\Something
```

For more information see [Embedding arguments into keyword names](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#embedding-arguments-into-keyword-names) in the robot framework user guide.